# what is the default rule for jaxb unmarshall the xml data?

Tags: java, jaxb

Want to know, having a class without any annotation, how the jaxb unmarshall the xml data to class.

I found it can take the following

If I have an node "label" in the xml

I have "_label" field in the class and "getLabel" and "setLabel" method.

jaxb can unmarshall it sucsessully. Just want to know its default rule.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The following is from the JAXB 2 specification ([JSR-222](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222)):

> **8.12    Default Mapping**
>
> This section describes the default
>   mapping of program elements. The
>   default mapping is specified in terms
>   of default annotations that are
>   considered to apply to a program
>   element even in their absence.
>
> **8.12.1  Java Identifier To XML Name**
>
> The following is the default mapping
>   for different identifiers:
>
> - class name: a class name is mapped to an XML name by de capitalization
>     using
>     java.beans.Introspector.decapitalize(class
>     name ).
> - enumtype name: enumtype name is mapped to an XML name by de
>     capitalization using
>     java.beans.Introspector.decapitalize(enumtype
>     name).
> - A property name (e.g. address) is derived from JavaBean access method
>     (e.g. getAddress) by JavaBean de
>     capitalization of the JavaBean
>     property name
>     java.beans.Introspector.decapitalize(JavaBeanAcc
>     essMethod)