# Can't parse XML files with generated JAXB classes

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb, xjc

I am trying to generate JAXB bindings from [this](http://sumo.dlr.de/xsd/net_file.xsd) xsd file according to [this tutorial](http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/generate-your-jaxb-classes-in-second/). Firstly I noticed that there are some dependencies, but I managed to get them off the same address. After I downloaded them I ran

```
xjc net_file.xsd
```

This did generate some java code, however unlike in the tutorial the files look like "...Type.java". I find this inconvenient, but I could live with it.
After that I tried to parse the [given](http://sumo.dlr.de/trac.wsgi/browser/trunk/sumo/tests/complex/tutorial/quickstart/data/quickstart.net.xml) example file:

```
File file = new File("quickstart.net.xml");
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(NetType.class);
Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
NetType net = (NetType) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
```

However, I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"net"). Expected elements are (none)
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Take a look at this, may be similar to your question [similar_Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203312/javax-xml-bind-unmarshalexception-unexpected-element-uri-localgroup)

Comment: "net" should be your root element for example XmlRootElement(name="net"). can you show NetType class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found the problem. It seems that you actually need to use the generated `ObjectFactory`. I modified the code like this:

```
    File file = new File("quickstart.net.xml");
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(ObjectFactory.class);
    Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
    JAXBElement<NetType> netElement = (JAXBElement<NetType>) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
```

Now everything works. I guess the reason is that the `ObjectFactory` has an annotated builder method:

```
/**
 * Create an instance of {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link NetType }{@code >}}
 * 
 */
@XmlElementDecl(namespace = "", name = "net")
public JAXBElement<NetType> createNet(NetType value) {
    return new JAXBElement<NetType>(_Net_QNAME, NetType.class, null, value);
}
```

Imho this is really over-engineered but whatever :)

Answer (score 0):

I think your XML file is defined by two XSDs. See here:

`xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://sumo.dlr.de/xsd/netconvertConfiguration.xsd"` and `xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://sumo.dlr.de/xsd/net_file.xsd`

You will either miss `net` or `configuration` element.

I don't know how JAXB can support partial XSDs. Are you sure you follow the tutorial correctly? You should be able to merge these two xsd files into one (?).