# XML unmarshal to Object in Java/Kotlin

Tags: java, xml, kotlin, jaxb, unmarshalling

I want to change a xml string to a object but it seems like keeps throwing error to me and I'm not sure how to use those @XmlRootElement stuff

**Just view/reply it as JAVA also can although written in kotlin**

Here it's the XML string

```
<xml>
<return_code><![CDATA[SUCCESS]]></return_code>
<return_msg><![CDATA[OK]]></return_msg>
<appid><![CDATA[wx0b6dc231d20b379f1]]></appid>
<mch_id><![CDATA[1508319851]]></mch_id>
<nonce_str><![CDATA[mqy4nB6xGoyC1QPY]]></nonce_str>
<sign><![CDATA[2D9A3195E196F679D3916C5DC74754B4]]></sign>
<result_code><![CDATA[SUCCESS]]></result_code>
<prepay_id><![CDATA[wx2116190646297891sfae86747980208850875]]></prepay_id>
<trade_type><![CDATA[JSAPI]]></trade_type>
</xml>
```

Here it's my data class

```
@XmlRootElement
data class  WxPayResult(


val return_code: String = "",

val return_msg: String = "",


//return_code as SUCCESS will only return the following params
val appid: String? = null,

val mch_id: String? = null,

val device_info: String? = null,

val nonce_str: String? = null,

val sign: String? = null,

val result_code: String? = null,

val err_code: String? = null,

val err_code_des: String? = null,


//return_code and result_code both as success will only return the following params
val trade_type: String? = null,

val prepay_id: Int? = null,

val code_url: String? = null
)
```

Here it's my code, *"xmlreturn" is the xml string*

```
val jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(WxPayResult::class.java)
        val unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller()

        val reader = StringReader(xmlreturn)
        val person = unmarshaller.unmarshal(reader)
```

Here it's the error

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"xml"). Expected elements are <{}wxPayResult>
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleEvent(UnmarshallingContext.java:741)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:262)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:257)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportUnexpectedChildElement(Loader.java:124)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext$DefaultRootLoader.childElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:1149)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext._startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:574)
```

I know probably i need to add something into the data class but i don know what to add. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"Group")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203312/javax-xml-bind-unmarshalexception-unexpected-element-uri-localgroup)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your root element's name differs from your xml root element, which also the message suggests. It expects `wxPayResult`, but you give it a `xml`.

Either deliver an XML with `wxPayResult` as root element or supply the `name` to `XMLRootElement`, e.g.

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "xml")
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I did tried  adding  (name ="xml")  but it can't get the value out means that i get all property in null in the Person object. Do you get any idea of why this happen?

Comment: Yes, you need `@XmlElement` on each element. Note: if the name differs there too you can also supply a `name`-attribute.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/nsnaY9x      Here is the picture on wat i get, do you mind/know how i gonna do this @XmlElement?

Comment: Sample: `@XmlElement var return_code : String? = null`. You may need to switch to `var`.

Comment: Just tested `val`. You do not need `var`, `val` will work too... so it only depends whether you want to alter your variable or not ;-)

Comment: thanks Bro, but i tried with `val` and it won't get the value, i not sure why(if u don mind dive into this) but since `var` did the job, im okay with it. 

but i have another issue on marshalling, can you also help me if you don mind. Thanks again so much.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51997055/xml-unable-to-create-jaxbcontext-on-marshal

Comment: hmmm... actually, `val` works, if you do not use it in the constructor, e.g. `@XmlRootElement(name="xml") class WxPayOrder() { @XmlElement val demo : String = "a" }` will populate `demo` with `"b"` if you unmarshall the following xml: `<xml><demo>b</demo></xml>`... (however that might not really make sense, as within the code you could never set `demo` to anything else then `a`... except using reflection)