# XML unable to create JAXBContext on marshal

Tags: java, xml, kotlin, jaxb, marshalling

I have a POJO(in Kotlin) that I wanted to change into XML but i having problem going through the  `JAXBContext.newInstance(myObj::class.java)` part

**Just view/reply it in Java/Kotlin also can**

Here's my code on marshalling

```
val context = JAXBContext.newInstance(WxPayOrder::class.java)
val m = context.createMarshaller()

m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true)

val sw = StringWriter()
m.marshal(wxPayOrderWithSign, sw)
val xmlString = sw.toString()
```

Here's my code on the POJO or data class ***(I tried both and neither with/without 
@XmlType & @XmlElement  ON)***

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "WxPayOrder")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(propOrder = arrayOf("appid","attach","body","detail"))
data class  WxPayOrder (

        @XmlElement(name = "appid")
        var appid: String,

        @XmlElement(name = "attach")
        var attach: String? = null,

        @XmlElement(name = "body")
        var body: String,

        @XmlElement(name = "detail")
        var detail: String? = null,
)
```

Here's is the error i getting *(I personally think that wasn't informative enough and i saw others that hit this error also come with duplicate name etc.. but not mine)*

```
com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException$Builder.check(IllegalAnnotationsException.java:106)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:471)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:303)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:139)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1156)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:165)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:247)
```

Here's my part of my pom.xml *(i just include part of it because i scare i left out something important that you guys might able to see it)*

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-impl -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

I'm quite new to Kotlin and JAXB. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You already asked something similar... the actual cause of the problem is the same. Please also look at answers of questions you asked in the past. Sometimes other people may find it useful if you upvote them or mark it as solved, if the answers are helpful. In this case actually, it is the solution to your current problem ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JAXB requires a no-arg-constructor to work. Maybe somewhere in your stacktrace/log that was also written... but maybe not.

As you used a data class, the simplest way to fix the issue is to add a `no-arg-constructor` as follows:

```
@XmlRootElement
data class WxPayOrder (
        // all the properties
) {
  // the no-arg-constructor is a must:
  constructor() : this("", body = "", /* all the other properties that must have a value, setting them to a default one */)
}
```

If it was a "simple" `class` you can also use something similar to:

```
@XmlRootElement
class WxPayOrder() { // actually now this line contains the no-arg constructor
   // your properties
   lateinit var demo : String
   // your custom constructors
   constructor(demo : String) : this() {
     this.demo = demo
   }
}
```