# I want to convert XML to Java by unmarshalling

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, unmarshalling

This is my XML, and I want to unmarshall it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<departments>
    <deptname name="Research">
        <employee>
            <eid>r-001</eid>
            <ename>Dinesh R</ename>
            <age>35</age>
            <deptcode>d1</deptcode>
            <deptname>Research</deptname>
            <salary>20000</salary>
        </employee>
    </deptname>
    <deptname name="Sales">
        <employee>
            <eid>s-001</eid>
            <ename>Kanmani S</ename>
            <age>35</age>
            <deptcode>d2</deptcode>
            <deptname>Sales</deptname>
            <salary>30000</salary>
        </employee>
    </deptname>
</departments>
```

Department.java

```
public class Department 
{ 
    @XmlAttribute(name = "deptname")
    private String name;

    @XmlElement(name = "employee") 
    private List<Employee> employee = new ArrayList<>();//getter and setter//
}
```

This is my Departments.java

```
public class Departments {

    List<Department> deptname;

    public List<Department> getDeptname() {
        return deptname;
    }

    public void setDeptname(List<Department> deptname) {
        this.deptname = deptname;
    }
}
```

This is my Unmarshalling.java

```
public class Unmarshalling {
    public void testXML() {
        try {
            File file = new File(
                "/home/scrunch/work/workspace/sts/default/EmployeeUnmarshall/src/main/java/OutputXml.xml");
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Departments.class);
            Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
            Departments departments = (Departments) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
            System.out.println(departments);
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried unmarshalling but i didn't get the java object .I got xml format. I am doing the Rest service. For that, I need to unmarshall the 
 XML file, so then I could get the Java objects.Could you please update me sir.

Comment: In that above code Research department inside 4 more employees belongs to research department and same as sales department also. i tried to Un marshall , but i didn't get the java format.I got the output xml format only.Could you please update me , how i will do.

Comment: I created two java classes,one is Department.java---

Comment: This is my Department.java ----public class Department {
  @XmlAttribute(name = "deptname")
   private String name;

   @XmlElement(name = "employee")
   private List<Employee> employee = new ArrayList<>();----//getterand setter//

Comment: This is my Departments.java-----public class Departments {

 List<Department> deptname;

 public List<Department> getDeptname() {
  return deptname;
 }

 public void setDeptname(List<Department> deptname) {
  this.deptname = deptname;
 }


}

Comment: This is my Unmarshalling.java---public class Unmarshalling {
 public void testXML() {
     try {
      
       File file = new File("/home/scrunch/work/workspace/sts/default/EmployeeUnmarshall/src/main/java/OutputXml.xml");
       JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Departments.class);
     
       Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
       Departments departments = (Departments) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
       System.out.println(departments);
     } catch (JAXBException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
     }
 }
}

Comment: Hi Latha, welcome to stackoverflow. It is better to edit your question with additional information. Can you add all comments you added here in the question itself?

Comment: This may be relevant example : https://www.mysoftkey.com/java/jaxb-nested-list-of-java-object-example/

Comment: "I have tried to unmarshall it, but I couldn't get the output." How? What is the error?

Comment: It is not showing any error, but the output came in xml only not  java object?

Comment: Try to print 'jaxbContext.marchall(departments)'  instead of 'departments'
Also you can put debug breakpoint to see whether departments object is fulfilled after unmarshalling.

Comment: sorry sir,i tried but i didn't get it.i want unmarshalling the above xml file.

Comment: `@XmlRootElement public class Departments`. But maybe first try working examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code and ended up having this error:

> Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"departments"). Expected elements are (none)

Fixed it by declaring `Departments` this way:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="departments")
public class Departments {

    List<Department> deptname;

    public List<Department> getDeptname() {
        return deptname;
    }

    public void setDeptname(List<Department> deptname) {
        this.deptname = deptname;
    }
}
```

See [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203312/javax-xml-bind-unmarshalexception-unexpected-element-uri-localgroup/5203390)

Have a try

Comment: Thank you sir, i got the output.

Comment: I have one more doubt sir, As you said like that i created java classes ,now i am doing rest service for the above xml .I am struck in controller.How i will map in controller.

Comment: @Latha You should make an other question for that as it is not related to the XML parsing. It depends on what framework you are using, if any, also you need to describe your endpoint, I guess it would be a POST accepting an XML payload.